# How do i write nested JSON into HashMap<String,String>?

Tags: android, json, hashmap

JSON:

```
{
    "deviceId": "AAAAAAA1",
    "cardInfo": {
        "pan": "123456789012345",
        "psn": "00",
        "cvv": "123",
        "panExpiryDate": "2017-12-12"
    },
    "productType": "CREDIT",
    "requestor": 1234,
    "aid": "A000000001234567",
    "aidVersion": 1,
    "panSource": null,
    "deviceLanguage": "en"
}
```

Android Code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    final String newdata=bundle.getString("newdata");

    try {
        js=new JSONObject(newdata);
        di=js.getString("deviceId");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    postDataParams.put("deviceId",deviceID);
    postDataParams.put("cardInfo.pan",card);
    postDataParams.put("cardInfo.psn",Psn);
    postDataParams.put("cardInfo.cvv",cvv);
    postDataParams.put("cardInfo.panExpiryDate",panExpiryDate);
    postDataParams.put("productType",productType);
    postDataParams.put("requestor",requestor);
    postDataParams.put("aid",aid);
    postDataParams.put("aidVersion",aidVersion);
    postDataParams.put("panSource",panSource);
    postDataParams.put("deviceLanguage",deviceLanguage);

    response = service.postServerData(path,postDataParams);

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(response);
        System.out.println("success " + json.get("success"));
        success = json.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

On writing this code am not getting any response from the url. Can you please help where i did the mistake.

Comment: "Send me a complete code" won't work here on Stackoverflow, this is a place for questions and answers, not for asking others to code for you for free. Please describe your problem, add relevant code that you're struggling with and hopefully somebody will be able to help.

Comment: What format do you want the keys of the resulting `HashMap` to be? What doesn't work, or is incomplete about, the code you posted?

Comment: You need to take hasmap of string object type.and in that hashmap put one json object with key cardInfo.

Comment: have added the code....please help

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
postDataParams.put("cardInfo.pan",card);
postDataParams.put("cardInfo.psn",Psn);
postDataParams.put("cardInfo.cvv",cvv);
postDataParams.put("cardInfo.panExpiryDate",panExpiryDate);
```

to this

```
JSONObject cardInfoJson = new JSONObject();
cardInfoJson.put("pan", card);
cardInfoJson.put("psn", psn);
cardInfoJson.put("cvv", cvv);
cardInfoJson.put("panExpiryDate", panExpiryDate);
postDataParams.put("cardInfo", cardInfoJson);
```

Comment: Sorry its not working.. Where can i send you the complete code? Could you please tell.